# Using a background image in Django using static and variable

Tags: html, django

I've seen a lot of these types of questions but none are using a {{ variable_name }} in the html using background. For context, I'm trying to insert a unique photo as a background image for every page.The name of the picture associated with every page that is to be inserted onto that page as the background image can be called with {{ item.name }}

```
<heading id="background-image" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/pattern.jpg' %});">
```

This will work for a specific background image, "pattern", but I want it to be dependent on a variable for that specific page.

The following code will import the correct image on the page, but it needs to be turned to a background image (so that I may put text in front)

```
<img src="{% static 'img/' %}{{ item.name }}.jpg" alt="item picture">
```

So, I'd have to do something like this, in theory, for the background image, but it doesn't work. What are some other ways to introduce a variable in a static manner for the URL field?

```
<heading id="background-image" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/'}{{ item.name }}'.jpg' %});">
```

Comment: Why don't you apply the same solution to your style attr?

Comment: @IvanStarostin not sure what you mean

Comment: If you know how to produce such an URL for `img` what is stopping you from doing the same for `background-image`. Your question contains the solution for _"using 'static' and variable"_, so what are you asking?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Updated the question. I am asking how to introduce the variable, {{ item.name }}, in the URL field for the background-image, as well as using the static field to get the images from the static folder.

Comment: What you've done in background-image is not the same as in img.src - take another look. Yes, this syntax is broken.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I've tried a lot of different syntax variations of this. If you have any insight on what it _should_ be, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <heading id="background-image" style="background-image: url(' {% static 'img/' %}{{ item.name }}.jpg');">
```

A couple of ticks were in the wrong place. What an annoying, tiny issue I spent days working on!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<heading id="background-image" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/' %}{{ item.name }}.jpg);">
```

`static` needed to be closed (`%}`) before `{{`. You were very close to the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. The path isn't being built correctly through the HTML file on the browser; it looks like this: `<heading id="background-image" style="background-image: url(/static/img/'.jpg');">` as you can see, the {{ item.name }} field isn't being properly added. I'm beginning to think this simply isn't valid code.

Comment: Quotes were unnecessary - fixed it. Item or item.name is not initialized and syntax has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Show your real template and view code so we could help.